# mailchimp campaign sending type webhook

Tags: mailchimp

I set up a webhook type "campaign sending".
Next to webhook handler when sending a message within the campaign comes the following set of fields:

```
"type": "campaign",
"fired_at": "2009-03-26 21:31:21", 
"data[id]": "5aa2102003",
"data[subject]": "Test Campaign Subject", 
"data[status]": "sent",
"data[reason]": "", 
"data[list_id]": "a6b5da1054"
```

Now I'm trying to get an email (member) to which this webhook has initialized.

I can get a campaign via data[id] (campaign_id) field of webhook data:

```
/3.0/campaigns/{campaign_id}
```

and then i can get list of sended emails in this campaign:

```
/3.0/reports/{campaign_id}/sent-to
/3.0/reports/{campaign_id}/email-activity
```

the result of these methods contains the required email, but there are other results contains too, and the order of their output does not match the last activity.

anyway, I haven't been able to get the last email handled yet.

thanks for help.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking - can you edit the question?

Comment: @James I asked if there was a correct way to get the subscriber (or subscriber ID) the sending of which caused the triggered webhook? In the end, decided through the processing of the list of recent campaign events, but this solution does not seem optimal.